# Connecting your application to a database in another PC through the internet

Tags: c#, database, connect

I am new to the idea of connecting my application to an online database and by online, I mean a database from another PC that I need to access by using the internet.

I am not new to accessing a local database, in fact, I made a class that stores all the parameters that I need to connect to a database.

Can anyone help me? What do I need to configure in my SQL Server and in my codes to make it accessible through the internet? I hope someone can help me. Thanks!

Comment: First off, you should never expose a DB server directly to the internet. Secondly, explain a bit more as to your setup: Is the server behind a firewall? Do you control the target server/environment?

Comment: I'm not really exposing my DB to the internet. I just want a specific computer to access my  db through the internet.

Comment: yes the server is behind a firewall. and yes, i control the server.

Comment: A good read: [How to make SQL Server visible on internet](http://serverfault.com/questions/306053)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your comments (and question) you mention that you have a specific server that needs to talk to a specific server. There are a few options:

1. Expose the sql server directly to the internet and use the IP to
   connect. **THIS IS A BAD IDEA...** This opens you up to hacks, port
   scans, and generaly bad things.
2. Use a VPN from one machine to the other and use an IP address within the VPN. As long as your VPN is correctly set up and secure; this negates the security problems in option 1.
3. Use a web service to expose the SQL server over the internet; require authentication in the web service. You can even tie it to a remote IP so that it only accepts calls from your first machine. This is clean and tidy; it allows for expansion in the future (new machines, non SQL, other functions, etc). However it is the most complex option.

Myself I would use option 3; it may take longer but it is a good way to break apart the functionality and provides a way to expand in the future. However I suspect that option 2 may be your best bet for what you are asking.

Comment: so a VPN is my only choice. will it function the same as the number 1 but without the risk? and will I be able to connect another machine to it or I am limited to one? I'm sorry but I am a newbie to this. I have only worked on local projects.

Comment: Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network for info about VPNs. There are many providers (Windows has built in support that varies depending on the version of windows).

Basicly; a VPN is a private tunnel betwen two or more machines (one acts as a server others as clients) that creates a network within another network. For instance a private network over the internet.

Comment: so if a set up a vpn, when I put my application on the server machine along with the database. lets say I have 3 client machines, can they run my application simultaneously?

Comment: Yep. A VPN is basicaly the same as using physical network cables to link a number of machines together. You just need one machine (or a specialist bit of hardware) to act as what is called the "Gateway" into the VPN. In this case your server may be the sensible gateway.